# What Euro Truck Simulator 2 mod adds this Scania truck?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I just saw a video, in ETS2, and the person who was filming it had this truck but he didn't put a link, and I decided to search for that mod. I know one just like that, but without a 6X4 chassis, just with a 4x2, and I don't like 4x2.

I found a 6x4 SCANIA R700, looked just like the one in the video, however, it's GTS (German Truck Simualtor) mod. I've been searching for a ETS2 Scania R700 6x4 2013, but I can only find one for GTS.

I've tried the GTS version on ETS2 but this didn't work. I've been searching for 5 months, can't find. I have seen that guy having that same Scania on ETS2!

Heres the video:

Comment: The first answer is no where near right, even the bottom lights are diffrent.

Comment: @EZcheez hmm... I didn't notice that. I'll take a look and fix that in my answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

The truck you're looking for is a fictatious one called Scania **Evo**. You'll find various versions of it from different sites. [Here's one](http://www.simgamemod.com/scania-r700-new-v1-5-by-au44/). 
[image]

As for the wheels you can download [tuning mods](http://ets2.lt/en/category/detalestiuningas/) that will add such wheels to the modding shop, like [this one](http://www.ets2-mod.com/euro-truck-simulator-2-mods/wheels-pack-v2-0.html)

Comment: no 6x4 chassis...

Comment: @EZcheez Try [this one](http://ets2.lt/en/scania-r700-v-2-5-beta/), it's from the same author but it's newer (I haven't tested it).

Comment: @EZcheez The Scania Evo mods modify *existing* Scania trucks, rather than adding new ones. So you will have the same chassis options as with stock Scania trucks.

Comment: It seems both of the ones I've posted are standalone trucks and they don't replace any other. What's more is that they're locked, so you can't edit them. If you want the 6x4 or 6x2 just search for any scania evo that wasn't authored by au44. Be warned however that most of them are old and might slow down your game if they have lots of errors.

Comment: A point to note about trucks that replace existing ones is that sometimes as you are selecting the truck inside the truck dealership, it will be rendered as the old truck. It's only when you choose `customize configuration` or when you buy the truck that you will see the new body.